# php dynamic variable id

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I try to update or insert order in my data base but i have a problem because i have 2 ID the first (id_commande - auto increment) for the order and the second is for the member in relation of other table.

I can't find how i can call the id_commande.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // on teste si le visiteur a soumis le formulaire

    if (isset($_POST['commande']) && $_POST['commande'] == 'commande') {
        commander('homme', 'id_commande');
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['commande_femme']) && $_POST['commande_femme'] == 'commande_femme') {
        commander('femme', 'id_commande');
    }


    function commander($commande,$id_commande){

            // $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            // Connection au serveur
              $dns = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=carole';
              $utilisateur = 'acces_site';
              $motDePasse = 'password';
              $connection = new PDO( $dns, $utilisateur, $motDePasse );


            $req = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM commande WHERE id_commande = ?');
            $req->execute(array($id_commande));
            $stmt = $req->rowCount();

            if ($stmt == 1){
                // SI IL EXISTE 1 SINON 0 
                $sql = "UPDATE commande SET commande = :commande, quantite_commande = :quantite_commande WHERE id = :id";
                $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':commande', $commande);
                $stmt->bindParam(':quantite_commande', 'quantite_'.$commande);
                $stmt->execute(array(':commande' => $_POST[$commande], ':quantite_commande' => $_POST['quantite_'.$commande], ':id' => $id ));

            }
            else {

                $sql = 'INSERT INTO commande (id,commande,quantite_commande) VALUES (:id, :commande, :quantite_commande)';

                $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':commande', $commande);

                $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':commande' => $_POST[$commande], ':quantite_commande' => $_POST['quantite_'.$commande]));
            }


}
```

I need your help please !
Thx

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/php-dynamic-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use [PDO::lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php) for this?

Comment: $id = $connection -> lastInsertId() ;  I use that but it's don't work i have in my table id_commande and id i want to catch id_commande

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':commande' => $_POST[$commande], ':quantite_commande' => $_POST['quantite_'.$commande], ':id' => $id ));
```

how have you used $id while you haven't defined it before?!?!

Comment: i don't know how i can define this $id = $id_commande i want to create that but i don't find lol this $id must refer to the $id_command column in my table